# Increase Process Memory Usage to Stop System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: asp.net, exception, windows-server-2008-r2

Our .NET application is seeing a lot of System.OutOfMemoryExcpetions during our peak usage days which causes us to recycle the app pool. I'm stumped as what I can do to alleviate the problem. To give some background, our application dynamically generates sub-domains for each of our customers, and we have a lot of them, all separated into many different app pools (roughly 50 customers per app pool). We have a dedicated server with a 8 processor Xenon, and 56GB of memory, and the paging file is currently set to 20GB.

On average our server's physical memory usage is around 40% so I know our server can handle more. Now, I've read lots of articles explaining why this exception doesn't correlate to the total system memory, and has more to do with the processes in the application pools being overloaded.

So my question, is what can I do to allow these processes to have access to more memory per process?

UPDATE - I was asked to include a stack tace, here it one for the most recent execption. Please keep in mind, I'm not looking for how to fix the exception, but how to increase the memory the processes are allowed to consume:

> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._CompileMethod(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method)
>
> at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType)
>
> at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.Compile(SqlExpression
>   expression, Type elementType)
>
> at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.GetReaderFactory(SqlNode node, Type elemType)
>
> at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query)
>      at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery ``1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression
>   expression)
>
> at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>
> at Company.Task.TemplateTask.GetTemplateById(Template obj)

Comment: How about posting an exception stack trace?

Comment: Done, please keep in mind, I'm not looking for how to fix the exception, but how to increase the memory the processes are allowed to consume.